# How to set default for Notebook's Default Context

Tags: notebooks, customization, contexts

Every time I create a new notebook, I have to go into the settings and click

> Evaluation > Notebook's Default Context > Unique to This Notebook.

Is there any way to make Mathematica do this automatically when I create a new notebook?

Comment: If you search for `Context` in the options inspector, you might get what you need by selecting "Global Preferences" from the upper left drop down, and then setting the CellContext to Notebook

Comment: @JasonB. I'm having a hard time finding the options inspector.

Comment: @JasonB.: This worked for me.  Would you like to post it as an answer?  Or I can write one, if you'd prefer.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a programmatic way of what Jason has pointed:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, CellContext] = Notebook
```

This setting will persists across sessions so you can use `$FrontEndSession` too. Lookup those symbols to learn more.